# How to declare the url in a jQuery ajax request to execute an action from a zend controller?

Tags: zend-framework, jquery

I'm trying to implement an ajax request using jQuery in the Zend Framework. I created a controller with a test action as represented on the code below:

```
class CompareController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

public function init() {
    /* Initialize action controller here */

  }

public function indexAction() {
  }

public function testAction() {      
  }
}
```

My ajax request using jQuery looks like this:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",

            url:"<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'compare', 'action' => 'test')); ?>",

            data: dataString,
            success: function(msg) {
}
```

How should I declare the url to execute the test action from the zend controller upon receipt of the request?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use ***baseUrl()*** function like :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
        url:"<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/compare/test",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(msg) {

    }
});
```

Comment: When I do this it gets interpreted this as this: 

GET http://zend-cms.dev/%3C?php%20echo%20$this-%3EbaseUrl();%20?%3E/bug/ajax 404 (Not Found)

in the browser